# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException when parsing date

Tags: java, java-8

I am getting this exception when invoking that code:

```
String date = "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z";

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, ISO_INSTANT);
```

> The ISO instant formatter that formats or parses an instant in UTC,
>        * such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30Z'.

I want to check if date String is a valid date with pattern: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-07-21T17:32:28Z' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, InstantSeconds=1500658348, NanoOfSecond=0},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at MyTest.testRest(MyTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, InstantSeconds=1500658348, NanoOfSecond=0},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:461)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, InstantSeconds=1500658348, NanoOfSecond=0},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:368)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:456)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: What’s the stacktrace? We need the complete exception.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` and time zone is kind of a contradiction. First line of its documentation: *"A date-time without a time-zone..."* - not sure if that is the problem...

Comment: @stephanmathew check the pattern should be like yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'

Comment: Why are you trying to use `LocalDateTime`? It is timezoneless. Consider using `OffsetDateTime` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a datetimeformatter to perform this task easily. Try the below modified code

```
String date = "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z";

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;


Date testDate = Date.from(Instant.from(dateTimeFormatter.parse(date)));

System.out.print(testDate);
```

Comment: Why are you building a `java.util.Date`? The `java.time` classes are far superior and easier to use.

Comment: this was the solution i could think of. if you have a better solution please post it. Thanks

Comment: There is no **need** to transform to `java.util.Date`. Transform to `OffsetDateTime` or maybe `LocalDateTime`.